# Mysql query grouping by two columns for max date takes too long

Tags: mysql

I have table that looks like this:

```
l_p  l_a     l_timestamp          l_n   l_act   l_name
123  321     2011-1-1T01:00:00Z   B     q       das
21   23      2012-1-1T01:00:00Z   C     q       sd
123  23      2013-1-1T01:00:00Z   D     q       sad
21   321     2008-1-1T01:00:00Z   D     q       sad
21   23      2007-1-1T01:00:00Z   E     q       sad
```

The timestamp field is a binary. All other fields are varbinary. I am not interested in the l_name field but it is relevant for the indexes.

What I want to get back is for each unique combination of l_p and l_a the row with the max timestamp. I also have some additional conditions: the timestamp should be smaller than 2013-1-1 and the l_act field should be q. The table I want to get would look something like this:

```
l_p  l_a   l_timestamp          l_n   l_act
123  321   2011-1-1T01:00:00Z   B     q
21   23    2012-1-1T01:00:00Z   C     q
21   321   2008-1-1T01:00:00Z   D     q
```

The table contains about 50million records. My current query is extremely slow. It takes hours and still I haven't gotten a result yet. This is the query:

```
SELECT a.l_p,a.l_a,a.l_timestamp,
case a.l_new
when 'B' then 2
when 'C' then 3
...
end as GN
FROM tmp a
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT l_a,l_p,MAX(l_timestamp) as max_date
FROM tmp
WHERE l_act = 'q' AND (l_n != 'I' and l_n != 'Z')
AND l_timestamp < cast('2013-01-01T00:00:00Z' as binary)
GROUP BY l_p,l_a) b
on (a.l_p = b.l_p AND a.l_a = b.l_a AND
a.l_timestamp = b.max_date AND
a.l_act = 'q' AND  (l_n != 'I' and l_n != 'Z')
```

I've also tried this variation with the same results:

```
SELECT a.l_p,a.l_a,a.l_timestamp,
case a.l_new
when 'B' then 2
when 'C' then 3
...
end as GN
FROM tmp a
(SELECT l_a,l_p,MAX(l_timestamp) as max_date
FROM tmp
WHERE l_act = 'q' AND (l_n != 'I' and l_n != 'Z')
AND l_timestamp < cast('2013-01-01T00:00:00Z' as binary)
GROUP BY l_p,l_a) b
WHERE (a.l_p = b.l_p AND a.l_a = b.l_a AND
a.l_timestamp = b.max_date AND
a.l_act = 'q' AND  (l_n != 'I' and l_n != 'Z'))
```

The indexes on the table are:

```
Keyname     Type         Unique    Packed   
PRIMARY     BTREE        Yes       No   
Field       Cardinality            Collation
l_project   18           A      
l_name      18           A  
l_a         24799255     A  
l_act       49598510     A  
l_timestamp 49598510     A

AND
Keyname     Type          Unique Packed 
l_a         BTREE         No     No 
Field       Cardinality          Collation
l_a         16532836      A     
l_name      16532836      A
```

Any ideas on why it takes so long? The table is innodb.

Comment: What about a siple group by? `select l_a, l_b, max(timestamp) as max_time from tmp where timestamp < cast('2013-01-01T00:00:00Z' as binary) group by l_a, l_b` I can not yet understand what the subselects are for.

Comment: Yes that would work but I am also obtaining a.l_n in my select process. A simple group and max doesn't work properly because it just picks any random row from l_n while I want the one that corresponds to the max(timestamp) per pair l_a,l_p

Comment: What does EXPLAIN show? Paste that into your question.

Comment: Would be useful to know but since the query has not completed for what it is 12 hours by now, I won't know what explain has to say.

Comment: The isolated explain of the inner subquery may be easier obtained, because `explain` may take a long time for the complete query.

Comment: The inner part returns (and really fast)
id select_type table type possible_keys key key_len ref rows Extra
1 SIMPLE tmp ALL NULL NULL NULL NULL 49396274 Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT 1: The query below is quite like the original query. It very much depends on how strict are the other conditions, i.e. how many rows can be ignored with those conditions. I think the index should contain the group-max-triple `(l_a, l_b, timestamp)`, but if `l_act='q'` is a strong reduction and the condition is always there then `l_act` should come before l_a.

Origin:
I would write it as

```
select tmp.* 
from tmp inner join (
    select l_a, l_b, max(timestamp) as max_time 
    from tmp where timestamp < cast('2013-01-01T00:00:00Z' as binary) 
    group by l_a, l_b
) as selmax 
on selmax.l_a = tmp.l_a 
   and selmax.l_b = tmp.l_b 
   and selmax.max_time = tmp.timestamp
;
```

and give tmp an index on `(l_a, l_b, timestamp)`.

And also: what says `explain`?

EDIT 2:

Seeing the explain and looking at the indices clears the case. l_project starts the primary key but you give no restriction on that in your inner query.

The second index needs `name` as a second field.

If l_act is a strong restriction (All of the queries give a `l_act` - condition which meets less than  1/3 of the table), you should make an index

```
l_act, l_a, l_b, timestamp
```

otherwise

```
l_a, l_b, timestamp
```

If the 4-part-index is used, it should be very fast.

I wish much fun adding the index. ;-)

If you use the 4-part-index, then you must add the l_act-condition in the inner AND the outer join.

Comment: I wrote the same query. Keep in mind that l_act and l_n might need to be indexed, too.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, it's just the same (as I saw too late). Then only the `explain` could give a hint, especially the inner explain. It could be necessary to insert a `use index`.

Comment: I started preparing the index and its been hours and still its been built. I tried this query however and it actually is processed up to a point fast but now it gets stuck at "sending data" status.
I set "INTO OUTPUT" so that i can see what is happening and apparently data are sent to the file when I do tail on linux but they are exported extremely slowly. It takes a couple of minutes for 100 rows and it happens in increments (so 100 rows are pasted and then wait 100 secs and the again 100 rows...). Note: this is still without the indexes which are currently being built.

Comment: firing the query and building the index are two operations on the same table. Every query will be waiting for the index-operation, and the index waits for a running query. I would advise to stop the original select, build the index and then fire the query.  //   Hint: For analytical tests you could use a smaller version of the table, say `create table tmp_test like tmp; insert into tmp_test select * from tmp where rand() < 0.001;` - then checking and timing different versions is a bit more fun.

Comment: What if I were to create a new tmp table, create there all the indexes and the structure of the original, and then do an insert select? Would that be faster instead of rebuilding indexes?

Comment: No, normally not. If it is really for a one-shot and you want to hurry up you could write the result of the inner select into a different table. That still does not speedup the outer select. You could process every single result of the inner select in your code.

Comment: Yeap, but still I would require to pick the triplets which is essentially what is slowing down the process. The inner select takes 30-60 minutes but then the outer where "sending data" takes place takes a long time because it tries to find triplets for 24 million records(inner select) vs the original 50 million records table. Question is, would the index help speed up the process of finding triplets?

Comment: As long as l_a, l_b, timestamp leeds to a small amount of or a single triple then 24 millions is definitely not a big number.